# Alternating Color of Rows with Merged Rows in Leading Column - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel sheet that will be tracking some of our autonomous processes and their access privileges at my company and I've run into an issue with Excel..

I'm trying to alternate row colors, which in and of itself isn't an issue, however the fact that I've got merged rows are giving me issues.

As of right now I've got 5 columns with headers in A through E. Column F is being used for conditional formatting to color the rows. In column F this formula is present:

`=MOD(IF(ROW()=2,0,IF(A2=A1,F1, F1+1)), 2)`

This works great if I want to repeat the leading Column item over and over, however I'd like to reduce the visual clutter and increase clarity, so I've merged some of the rows in the Column A because multiple rows in B:E correspond to it.

I've merged A2:A4 right now and the formula picks up the A2 and A4 as blank, but A3  (the text in the merged cell is centered) is recognized as different that A2 and A4 because the text resides there. I'll upload an image to give a better idea of what I'm talking about as well.

If anyone can give me a tip on how to alternate row colors with merged cells/rows that'd be great, I've done a lot of googling and searching on stackoverflow, but for the most part I've only found things that pertain to unmerged rows/cells.

Image Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enVor.jpg

### =IF() Condition that worked for me:

`=MOD(IF(ROW()=2,0,IF((A2=0),IF((OR(A1<>0,A2=A1)),F1, F1+1),F1+1)), 2)`

There is an answer below with a picture I posted, however, for most situations I would recommend the method suggested by @BruceWayne. It's far more sensible than working with merged cells!

Comment: Is there a requirement to use merged cells? Typically, as you're seeing, merged cells cause more headaches than ...non-headaches.  Is it just to format the information a little easier?

Comment: It's mainly to increase clarity when reading the sheet, it's going to end up getting pretty cluttered with repeated entries, so ideally I could merge the leftmost column to give a clear indication where one process ends and another begins, but if there is a better solution to preserve the legibility of the document then that could also be a solution, but none come to mind for me, I'm not well versed in making aesthetically pleasing and useful Excel sheets.

Is there a way I could reference the leftmost cell of the one the formula is in? I think that would default it to the proper cell..

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a solution with just some clever working with the Conditional IF() statements. I think the key was taking into account that the Merged Cells that weren't the top (i.e. If I merged A2:A4, A2 is top, A3, A4 bottom) were equal to 0 while the top was set to the value of the text within the merged cell. Using the formula below I was able to achieve the result I was after:

`=MOD(IF(ROW()=2,0,IF((A2=0),IF((OR(A1<>0,A2=A1)),F1, F1+1),F1+1)), 2)`

And here is a linked screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn4wN.jpg

I then just added conditional formatting for every row but row 1: `=$F2=1`. I'll be hiding column F to make it seem less obtrusive.

For future reference, I would agree with what @BruceWayne mentioned in that a simpler formatting that gets the job done would be preferable. There are many other ways to format this in a way that makes much more sense, but I felt like I was close when I was tinkering with it, so I stuck with it another 15 minutes or so and was able to pull out a usable formatting condition.

Answer (score 0):

Might I make a suggestion?  If the merging rows is to increase clarity with repeated entries, perhaps we can use another Conditional Formatting rule to make it more legible.

Say you have data that looks like this:

[image]

But, we don't want to see `<Process #>` duplicates in the A column.  We could merge these cells and center it along the rows. But again, merging cells is generally frowned upon I've found. (It makes it tricky to format, conditional format, copy/paste, do any `VLOOKUP()`/`Index/Match`, etc.)

First, let's get the rows alternating colors. I'm using fill of RGB(183, 255, 253):

**New Rule 1 -** 
Formula: `=MOD(ROW(),2)`
Applies To Range: `$A$2:$E$9`
Format: Fill with color RGB 183, 255, 253 (...or whatever you want, just note the RGB for later)

Now, we get this:
[image]

Okay, making progress.  Now, let's work on hiding the duplicate values in column A.

So, let's apply some more Conditional Formats. We'll need two for column A, one to set the font to White, one to set the Font to that blue fill color.

**New Rule 2 -**
Formula: `=AND($A3=$A2,MOD(ROW(),2)=1)`
 
Applies To: `=$A$3:$A$100`
Format: Font --> Color --> RGB(183, 255, 253)

**New Rule 3 -**
Formula: `=AND($A3=$A2,MOD(ROW(),2)=0)`
Applies To: `=$A$3:$A$100`
Format: Font --> Color --> White

Now we have:
[image]

IMO, we can do one more thing to clarify the breaks in Processes:

**New Rule 4 -**
Formula: `=$A2<>$A1`
Applies To: `=$A$2:$E$100`
Format: Border --> Top Border

Now, we have a nice new CF table.
[image]

Comment: In hindsight, yes, this would be a much better option, but I was able to get a working condition for the formatting with the merged cells. Since my excel sheet I'm making is pretty straightforward, I don't think there should be any issues with my posted answer, but in larger, more complex sheets this would certainly be the desired option.

Comment: Sorry for rehashing this question, but with this method, how does it handle having rows being inserted? With each process there is always the potential for a new Credential to be added that must be appended to the process in the sheet. In a previous working version of this method, I had issues with adding rows. It breaks the formatting, and even when trying to reapply the formatting it won't fix it because it's breaking the Formula by adding a "#REF!" into it.. (Image: https://imgur.com/a/DJEDTBa) Any help would be awesome!